# Item Selector Custom URL eXtension gives: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: itemselector

Installed the Item Selector Custom URL eXtension on SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 HR2.

Requesting the popup page (/extensions/itemselector/itemselectorpopup.htm)  gives 500 Internal Server Error.

Changed the server URL in the web.config to the DNS URL or the Windows Server name. Both cases server error 500.

Eventviewer does not show any error, Tridion log files does not show any error.

Changed the App pool to SDL Tridion and SDL Tridion x64, does not change the error

Comment: You really need to give a bit more detail about your setup, like what version of SDL Tridion are you using the Item Selector on and have you exactly followed the installation instructions? Also are you certain the `endpointAddress` is set to the correct Core Service version, because the `sdlTridionCmsUrl` is basically only used for the icons, if you have that incorrect you will just not see any icons? One last thing you could do is open the source in Visual Studio and run it from there, with the `net.tcp` endpoint you can build it on the CM server and debug it directly on there.

Comment: Version of SDL Tridion = 2011 SP1 HR2 (no other hotfixes).

Comment: Have exactly followed your instructions @ SDL Tridion World

Comment: I do not have Visual Studio.

Comment: endpointAddress is not used in the web.config of your ItemSelector.

Comment: I do not see any icons, immediately after requesting the ItemSelectorPopup.htm the response is: 500 Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 3):

The ready built version of the [Item Selector](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/itemselector.aspx) on SDL Tridion World, will only work on 2011 SP1, not sure if it still works for 2011 SP1 HR2, as I never checked that.

But there is an open source version available on [Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/sdl-tridion-world/source/browse/#svn/Item%20Selector/trunk), which you can build with the [Visual Studio Express](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx) edition (which you can download for free), and there you can specify different Core Service endpoints in the `web.config` to make it work with your exact version of SDL Tridion.

Please note the latest version on [Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/sdl-tridion-world/source/browse/#svn/Item%20Selector/trunk) is built against 2013 SP1, so you will need to change the Core Service endpoint and icon paths for 2011 SP1 HR2.

The ready built version is using `net.tcp://localhost:2660/CoreService/2011/netTcp` as a Core Service endpoint. I believe that should still be correct for 2011 SP1 HR2, but ofcourse it does mean that it only works directly on the COntent Manager Server itself (as it is using a `net.tcp` endpoint address).

This all being said, I would think the ready built version should work for you, but it is impossible for me to say what is going wrong with the limited information I get from you atm.